# Yii renders $content inside of my container div tag, but then closes the container div. Unintended?

Tags: html, yii, render

I recently started using the [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) framework trying to learn a little bit more about MVC.

I have currently made a view whose markup looks similar to the following:

```
<div id=container">
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <?php echo $content?>
  <div id="separator"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

When the page loads the source file now looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="content">Content in here</div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Any idea what is causing Yii to forcefully close off my container div? When separator and footer are above the  line they are included in the container div so it is most likely something to do with Yii's rendering method. Oddly enough I cannot find any similar issues online.

I am trying to code cleanly so while I could just use another container for alignment and CSS3 purposes, being able to keep the separator and footer in the container div to begin with would be better.

Comment: Did you check the 'real' source-code (e.g. with wget) or the one from something like Firebug, browsers try 'fix' your - just in case - broken HTML if tags are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had pretty the same problem, but for me the problem was under IE(At least was visible under IE only. Wasn't have time to check why).
I solve the problem by changing a line of code in jquery.yiigridview.js (remaped via CGridView -> baseScriptUrl param):

```
    options = $.extend({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $.fn.yiiGridView.getUrl(id),
        success: function(data,status) {
            $.each(settings.ajaxUpdate, function(i,v) {
                var id='#'+v;
                $(id).html( $( data ).children() ); // was: $(id).replaceWith($(id,'<div>'+data+'</div>'));
            });
            if(settings.afterAjaxUpdate !== undefined)
                settings.afterAjaxUpdate(id, data);
            $('#'+id).removeClass(settings.loadingClass);
            $.fn.yiiGridView.selectCheckedRows(id);
        },
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I use renderPartial to render view with single CGidView in it.
In the controller have logic that check for ajax request and if is so, then rendering this subview and call Yii::app()->end(). In all other cases, controller renders regular view, that call renderPartial with single CGidView.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the css for this as well?

In case it helps, my structure is:

```
<container>
  <header>
    <menu>
    </menu>
  </header>
    $content
  <footer>
  </footer>
</container>
```

Comment: I'll post the css as a last resort as an update to the main post. It's a tad convoluted since I have significantly more sections than what is posted up top and they are all styled with 5-10 properties.

I am 99% sure the problem does not lie in the CSS itself but in the way Yii renders external files. It behaves the exact same way when I use any kind of widget as well. The included zii breadcrumb widget completely closes all divs up to the top of what it was in, as do all of my custom cportlet widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have a floating `</div>` tag somewhere in your content or layout views that is causing this error.  Yii is fairly 'dumb' (in the best of ways) in putting together your layouts and won't insert tags.

If you post your layout and views, we might be able to help you find the error.